# Burning Subtitle Track in Handbrake for HTML Player

Tags: video, html, handbrake

When I burn a subtitle track into a video using handbrake and upload it to my server, the html player doesn't show the subtitles, but when I play the video locally, they show just fine.
I never had this problem using HD video converter factory for windows, but since switching to ubuntu and using handbrake, the problem seems unavoidable.

Comment: It certainly isn't unavoidable if you actually select to burn the subtitle which isn't what you're doing, you're merely adding it as an element to a container. Local players are typically set to enable the first subtitle available, internal or external, by default. A HTML player isn't. But an actually burnt subtitle is part of the video so it doesn't matter, it's this simple. Plus, Handbrake is cross-platform so not even remotely an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I absolutely am selecting to burn the subtitle, and it shows locally not as an element, but as a burned subtitle. Why you just assume I'm not is the opposite of helpful. And I said I didnt start using handbrake UNTIL I switched to ubuntu. Ive burned dozens of subtitles before this in A DIFFERENT PROGRAM on Windows called HD Video Converter Factory, so I know what burnt subtitles look like and how they appear in both a local player and an html player. Perhaps I could point out that the burnt subtitles from Handbrake look to be getting cropped out by the html player.

Comment: Burnt subs (hard burn) do not show as subs at all in any player. If you can turn off the subs then they aren't burnt (sift subs). Cropping wasn't mentioned in the question but if that's the case video is being cropped and must look quite different in different players. It can happen with lettertbox video being zoomed in but I suspect this isn't the case here. https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/advanced/subtitles.html And about an interesting discussion about cropping, video resolution and re-encoding and how subs can be affected: https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/2038

Comment: I'm aware you used a different software in Windows and that's exactly the reason why I take an issue with the way you frame this question like it's somehow a Windows vs. Ubuntu and Ubuntu being at fault here. But you're comparing apples with oranges. Handbrake in Windows is expected to work the exact same way as in Ubuntu or MacOS. HD Video Converter Factory is Windows only so it can't be compared. Please read Method 3 - "How to hardcode subtitles Handbrake": https://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/how-to-hardcode-subtitles.html

Comment: @ChanganAuto correct I cannot turn the subtitles off after theyve been burnt. That is another way I know for a fact thats what Ive done. Im not blaming Ubuntu, my only point in mentioning ubuntu is to explain why I switched to handbrake from hd video converter factory as thats when the problem began. Also I know my issue is handbrake because I just tested the same video and subtitle combination with MistiQ, also for Ubuntu, and the "cropping?" issue went away; the burnt subtitles show fine in my html player.